# Vuefire how to setup db ref to dynamically change based on component props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I'm trying to setup dynamic binding of firebase node based on component data, like this

```
export default {
  name: 'data',
  props: {
    api: {
      type: String
    },
    section: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    apiData: { 
      source: (console.log('source', this.api), db.ref(this.api)),
      asObject: true
    }
  },  
  updated: function() {
    console.log('updated', this.api, this.section)
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log('created', this.api, this.section)
  }
}
```

My problem is, update event is fired, but apiData source update is not fired.

What is the correct way to do this with vuefire?

Answer (score 0):

After some reading of vuefire docs, I came up with watch solution

```
data: function(){
  return {
    apiData: {}
  }
},
created: function() {
    this.$bindAsObject('apiData', db.ref(this.api))
},
watch: {
  api: function() {
    this.$bindAsObject('apiData', db.ref(this.api))
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is this watch method? Where in the docs did you see this?

Comment: Watch is a simple way to trigger something on property change, as described here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html. The purpose of my example is to create reactive db property.